# Purging old data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here's my query:

```
select count(*),msg_date::timestamp::date 
from prod_itchbbo_p_small_message 
where msg_date::timestamp::date > date('2022-02-22')
group by msg_date::timestamp::date order by msg_date desc limit 10;
```

```
Output:
Count   msg_date
------  ---------
294975  2022-03-01
283762  2022-02-28
547437  2022-02-24
```

Then I run my function to remove the oldest:

```
select * from purge_olddata('2022-02-24') ;
```

How can I automate the purging by passing the msg_date to the function. I have to maintain at the most recent and the date after. Two dates with data must be maintained in the table.

Comment: Do you already have the purge_olddata() function in the system or you want a new one?

Comment: A new one will be very helpful.

Comment: is your requirement to pick the oldest set of records based on query-1 and pass it onto a function or procedure to delete the records relevant to that date?
You have a msg_date > in first query, does that need to be dynamic as well or that date is static?

Comment: Yes, pick up the oldest set of records but need to keep at least two recent days. The msg_date is dynamic. I am only doing it with static value because I am having trouble writing the SQL. Thanks.